# How to assign date ranges to arrays and compare against date input data

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I have an app which has a two date input fields. I have an existing function which extracts the number from each field and continually adds the digits until it produces a single digit. It then returns the respective numbers, and i display them with some text preceding them.

I want to create another function which does something similar, which takes the month and date (not year) of the input field, and then matches the date to an array ( i think?) of 12 different date ranges. And in the end, I want to simply assign this to a string of the astrology sign name. For example, a date of 04/09 (year not important) would yield, "aries". The important thing to remember here is that there are 12 ranges of dates (ex march 20-April 20) that i need to compare the input date to.

Im at a loss for how i can structure this function to do what I want. It seems i need to create an array with 12 different ranges of dates, and somehow check the input data against this array.

Any tips? Heres my existing javascript, and the html:

```
var ZodiacSigns = ['Aries', 'Taurus', 'Gemini', 'Cancer', 'Leo', 'Virgo', 'Libra', 'Scorpio', 'Saggitarius', 'Capricorn','Aquarius', 'Pisces'];




function getSum() {
// Place the id's of the input and output elements into respective arrays
let inputs = ['dateInput1','dateInput2'];
let outputs = ['result1','result2'];

// Loop over the items in the inputs array
// This will cause you to loop as many times as there are input elements
inputs.forEach(function(input, index){

// Instead of hard-coding the element id, you get the element reference
// from the .forEach callback function argument.
const inputValue = document.getElementById(input).value;
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < inputValue.length; i++) {
  const num = parseInt(inputValue.charAt(i));
  if (!isNaN(num)) {
    sum += num;
  }
}
const total = (sum - 1) % 9 + 1;
// And here, you reference the right output element, by using the corresponding
// index from the inputs array.
document.getElementById(outputs[index]).textContent = "Your number is: " + total;

});
}
```

---

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="cell-1" id="centerElement">
        <div id="cell-1-nest-l"></div>
        <div id="cell-2-nest-l"></div>
        <div id="cell-3-nest-l"></div>
        <div id="cell-4-nest-l"><h3>your name</h3></div>
        <div id="cell-5-nest-l"></div>
        <div id="cell-6-nest-l"><input type="text" class="nameStyle1" id="nameInput1"></div>

</div>

    <div class="cell-2" id="centerElement" ><img onclick="getSum();" 
src="file:///Users/Nineborn/Downloads/My%20Post%20(5).png" alt=""></div>

    <div class="cell-3" id="centerElement" >
            <div id="cell-1-nest"></div>
            <div id="cell-2-nest"></div>
            <div id="cell-3-nest"><h3>their name</h3></div>
            <div id="cell-4-nest"></div>
            <div id="cell-5-nest"><input type="text" class="nameStyle1" id="nameInput2"> 
 </div>
            <div id="cell-6-nest"></div>


            </div>

    <div class="cell-4" id="result1">
        <input type="date" class="dateStyle1" id="dateInput1">
            </div>

    <div class="cell-5"><button>Start Over</button></div>

    <div class="cell-6" id="result2"> 
        <input type="date" class="dateStyle2" id="dateInput2" placeholder="Their Bday">
            </div>
    <div class="cell-7"></div>

    <div class="cell-8"></div>

    <div class="cell-9"></div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of different ways of doing this. Below is a quick example doing exactly what you said, using an array of ranges to compare against.

Excercise left to reader to fill in actual zodiac dates.

```js
function getZodiac(day, month){

    // store the start/end ranges for the zodiacs
    let zodiacs = {
        'crab':{
            'start':[1,1],
            'end':[25,7]
        },
        'dog':{
            'start':[25,7],
            'end':[31,12]
        }
    }

    // loop through each property of 'zodiacs' in this case the property name is the zodiac_name
    for(let zodiac_name in zodiacs){

        // the object contains two properties 'start' and 'end'. Each of which is an array of two numbers. The first is the day, the second is the month.
        // so start[0] indicates this is the starting day, and end[1] indcates the ending day
        if(
            (month >= zodiacs[ zodiac_name ].start[1] && month < zodiacs[ zodiac_name ].end[1]) && // is the passed-in month in between the start and end for this?
            (day >= zodiacs[ zodiac_name ].start[0] && day < zodiacs[ zodiac_name ].end[0]) // is the passed-in day in between the start and end for this?
        ){
            console.log(`You're a ${zodiac_name}!`); // print out the name of this property!
        }
    }
}

getZodiac(1, 1); // you're a crab!
getZodiac(27, 7); // you're a dog!
```

Comment: thanks for this but i dont understand it at all, im pretty new

Comment: maybe you could put some extra comments on your answer?

Comment: Added some comments. Is there something in-particular that's confusing? Above only shows an object having its properties looped through.

Comment: I think the syntax for the objects you wrote is more advanced than my current knowledge. So am i correct that you have two objects inside of the object Zodiacs? And you have arrays within the crab and dog objects?

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I've edited it to be a bit more human-readable but it's the exact same thing.

Comment: Thank you. next question. I havent seen the syntax of the ' ' characters around the names. Can you explain the significance of them? The only object syntax i know of is something like: var Object = { name: "Ed", age: 32, }. So i dont understand the use of the characters around 'crab' etc. etc. I have probably three more questions if you dont mind haha but ill do one at a time. I appreciate the help!

Comment: So you could use `{name:"ED"}`, `{'name':"ED"}`, or `{"name":"ED"}` in the above interchangabley. But the first format would fail on an invalid identifier, but you can wrap those in quotes. eg: `{1st_name: "ED"}` would fail as JS identifiers can't start with a number, but `{"1st_name":"ed"}` would be fine. It's worth noting that JS Objects are not JSON despite the similarity. Actual JSON always needs the key wrapped in "double quotes" like the third example.

Comment: thanks, i dont recognize the syntax you wrote for the for loop. what is "in zodiacs"?

Comment: [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) is useful for looping through properties of an object (in this case crab and dog)

Comment: oh I've never seven seen for...in, thanks for clarifying.